# Unable to verify the first certificate - Traefik wildcard certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, https, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have traefik "traefik:v2.4.8" as a reverse proxy to docker container.

Everything works fine except the HTTPS request from server or Postman (request from frontend browser is fine)

The error is `Unable to verify the first certificate`

My workaround is to disable SSL verification on Postman and set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in other Nodejs app that request to this app

I don't know where the issue is but my company wildcard certs works fine in other project using Nginx as reverse proxy, I think I might misconfigured something in Traefik

I have little knowledge about TLS, HTTPS so I not sure how to troubleshoot this problem

Here is my config

traefik.yml

```yaml
log:
  level: DEBUG

entryPoints:
  web-secure:
    address: ":443"
  web:
    address: ":80"
providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: docker_network
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

  file:
    filename: "dyn.yaml"
    watch: true
api:
  dashboard: false

accessLog: {}
```

dyn.yml

```yaml
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /etc/certs/certs.crt
      keyFile: /etc/certs/certs.key
  stores:
    default:
      defaultCertificate:
        certFile: /etc/certs/certs.crt
        keyFile: /etc/certs/certs.key

  options:
    myTLSOptions:
      minVersion: VersionTLS12
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.0"
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4.8"
    container_name: "traefik"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - $PWD/traefik.yaml:/traefik.yaml
      - $PWD/dyn.yaml:/dyn.yaml
      - $PWD/certs/:/etc/certs/
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: docker_network
```

api docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: "npm start"
    expose:
      - 8080
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=docker_network"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-https.entrypoints=web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-https.priority=2"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-https.middlewares=backend-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-https.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-https.tls.domains[0].main=myapp.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-https.tls.domains[0].sans=*.myapp.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-https.tls.options=myTLSOptions@file"


      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-https.rule=Host(`myapp.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.backend-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/api"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.backend-http-secured.chain.middlewares=backend-http-redirect-to-https, backend-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.backend-http-redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"


      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-http.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-http.rule=Host(`myapp.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-http.priority=2"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend-http.middlewares=backend-http-secured"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: docker_network
```